# Laravel freeze time to time

Tags: laravel

I'm currently using laravel 7.24 in local development and.. experiencing freeze v'been years.

When it freeze, I usually go to the console and `ctrl+c` then something cancelled...? and after that laravel works fine. Mostly where I stuck in freeze status is log-in moment.

Is there something that I did wrong? or its unique problem of laravel?

I can't even figure out what should I more explain here..

Somewhere around I think I saw an article that laravel has chronicle problem about freezing.. Is actually existing problem? and.. if it exsits, my problem is one of them? Is this problem occurs after production?

Comment: Your console is freezing or the website?

Comment: Freeze both website and console. .. if freezing means nothing comes new when waits.

Comment: I have been working with Laravel for 5 years and I have never seen a freeze. If it freezes during log-in check what you have done, see if you have done something to freeze it. Without looking at your code we can't tell you what's wrong. Secondly, if your code is right and if it still freezes then most probably your pc/laptop has processor issues or browser issues. You can validate this issue, by checking it on an another pc/laptop.

Comment: What's your system specs? @GatesPlan